# Separation of Interstitial load from UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading, admob, interstitial, mopub

I created a simple android game and decided to put interstitial ads. My code(I'm using MoPub ad SDK, implementation is similar to admob):

```
private void loadMoPubInterstitial () {

    moPubInterstitialView.load();
}
```

and I call this from main activity's onCreate() method. The Interstitials are showing but it causes heavy load to UI thread. Console shows warning that some 350 frames are dropped and that the application is doing too many work on main thread. The game is really lagging in devices. When I commented the line

```
moPubInterstitialView.load();
```

the warning is removed and the game is running smoothly on device. So I decided to move the interstitial loading process to another thread. This was my code:

```
   private void loadMoPubInterstitial () {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            moPubInterstitialView.load();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

But this time, the interstitials are not showing. The check to decide whether the interstitials are ready or not:

```
moPubInterstitialView.isReady()
```

returns false always.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but i think you are checking the moPubInterstitialView before thread is finish doing the load work, just try to check the  moPubInterstitialView.isReady() once your thread is finished doing all the tasks.. I tried the below sample and it work for me.

```
boolean flag= false;
                temptest ="before change" ;
              Thread thread= new Thread(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       temptest=" text changed";
                        flag= true;
                   }
               });

                thread.start();


                if(flag)
                {
                    System.out.println(temptest);

                }
```

Comment: no. acutally there is enough time for the thread to load the required ad(the interstitial is shown after a minimum of 10 seconds from where the load function is called  which is more than enough).